# Create a loop that "displays" the bits in ax. The word "displays" means to put the bits into another register. Values in the other register is 0 or 1

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Assembly language programming

Store a value in ax.
Create a loop that "displays" the bits in ax.
The word "displays" means to put the bits into another register.
Values in the other register must be only 0 or 1.

I am doing it like this but I don't know I am doing it correctly or not. Please help.

```
.data 

x:
     .word 0b00101

.text                       

.globl _start                
                            

_start:  

     movw x, %ax
loop:
     
     cmp %ax, %bx
     
     je done
     
     andw 0b1000000000000000, %ax
     
     shl $1, %ax
     
     jmp loop
     
done:
     nop
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Note that nobody is going to do your homework for you.

Comment: You compare register `ax` with undefined register `bx`.  When the 15th bit of register `ax` is isolated by `andw`, all other bits are zeroed and cannot be investigated again in the following iterations. Note that the instruction [SHL](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr) copies the shifted-out bit into CF, you can use this to "display" the bit, for instance with instruction [ADC](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/adc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please use `SHL`, and `AND` instruction only

The trouble with this kind of condition is that we can't know what other instructions you are allowed to use. Your own example already uses `MOV`, `CMP`, `JE`, `JMP`, and even `NOP`.
Because the task asks for a **loop with precisely 16 iterations**, it's clear that it's just impossible to only use `SHL` and `AND`. We need at the very least a conditional jump and use an independent iteration counter.

The basic idea is always that `SHL` puts the bit that it shifts out, in the carry flag. From there, an instruction like `ADC` can pick it up and produce the result `BX=1`.

```
; IN (ax)
  mov  cx, 16
again:
  xor  bx, bx   ; BX=0
  shl  ax, 1    ; -> CF
  adc  bx, bx   ; BX=[0,1]
  loop again
```

Now I'll remove those `XOR`, `ADC`, and `LOOP` instructions that you yourself didn't use. This example only uses `MOV`, `SHL`, and `JNC`:

```
; IN (ax)
  mov  cx, 1
again:
  mov  bx, 0
  shl  ax, 1
  jnc  cont
  mov  bx, 1
cont:
  shl  cx, 1    ; Produces CF=1 after 16 iterations
  jnc  again
```

**Provided that the value in `AX` has its lowest bit set** (like in your example 0b00101), we can do without the independent iteration counter.

```
; IN (ax)
again:
  mov  bx, 0
  shl  ax, 1
  jnc  cont     \
  mov  bx, 1    | These don't change flags
cont:           /
  jnz  again    ; Still based on the flags from `shl ax, 1`
```

What will happen if you use this snippet on an `AX` value that does not have its lowest bit set, is that the loop will have less than 16 iterations!

---

And if you feel the urge to use the `AND` instruction at least once, you can use it to clear the `BX` register:

```
; IN (ax)
  mov  cx, 1
again:
  and  bx, 0    ; ANDing BX with zero produces BX=0
  shl  ax, 1    ; -> CF now has the bit that was shifted out at the high end of AX
  jnc  cont     ; That bit was 0, so BX=0 is fine
  mov  bx, 1    ; Else make BX=1
cont:
  shl  cx, 1    ; Produces carry after 16 iterations
  jnc  again
```

On successive iterations `CX` will hold 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 0
When the value finally becomes 0, the CF will get set because the true result of doubling the value (65536) no longer fits the 16-bit register.

Comment: @user16567153 Using [rotate RCR](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcl:rcr:rol:ror) instead of [shift](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr) has an advantage that after 16 iterations the contents of `ax` returns to its original state.

Comment: Sep Roland, can you please add comments also in the last code you provided.

Comment: @vitsoft In the code snippets in my answer, preserving the `AX` register would come from substituting `shl ax, 1` by `rol ax, 1`.  What was the idea of suggesting `RCR` to the OP? Perhaps some comments got deleted in the mean time?

Comment: My mistake, sorry, it should be `ROL` .  Or `ROR` if he wants to start from the least significant bit:  http://www.vitsoft.info/opta-cpu.gif

Comment: @vitsoft Can happen, thanks for replying.

Comment: Thanks - Sep Roland